# Logging exceptions together with structured arguments

Tags: java, slf4j, logstash-logback-encoder

Does anyone know what are best practices for logging exceptions together with structured arguments? Looking at https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#customizing-stack-traces, it is suggested to not use them but no alternative is provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just log exceptions as you would [normally log exceptions with slf4j/logback](https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-log-exceptions).  Specifically, provide the exception as the last argument to the log statement.

Examples

```java
// With no other arguments
logger.warn("Something bad happened", exception);

// With a regular (non-structured) argument
logger.warn("Something bad happened with {}", "foo", exception);

// With a structured argument
logger.warn("Something bad happened with {}", kv("foo", "bar"), exception);
```

Comment: It works, I made the mistake of putting the exception before the structured arguments and not tried the opposite. Thanks for the help!